# Escape string gets un-escaped in mysql concat function

Tags: mysql, escaping

I have following SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
(
    text_data varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
    SET @var_query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE col="',text_data,'"');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @var_query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

I call this SP like so `CALL sp_test('Screen size 4.3\"')`. I get an error. Then if I check value of @var_query variable, this is how it looks.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| @var_query                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT FROM sample_table WHERE col="screen size 4.3"" |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see the escaped " is getting un-escaped. If I hit this select statement directly with escaped double-quotes, it runs fine. So it means concat is removing un-escaping the escaped characters. How to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [how it have to be](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
SET @var_query = SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE col=?';
SET @data = text_data;
PREPARE stmt FROM @var_query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @data;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

while

> Escape string gets un-escaped in mysql concat function

is correct and the only proper behavior.

Comment: do we need to use concat function for this type of solution?

Comment: We should **never** use concat function for this type of solution!

Comment: no I mean, in the solution that you mentioned here, you have used concat where nothing is getting concatenated. That's why I asked

Comment: Ah I see. it was copy-paste bug. fixed

Comment: Ok so basically, `USING` clause replaces all `?` with values of the variables. I tried something like this `'INSERT INTO sample_table_?(col1) VALUES (?)'` and then `EXECUTE stmt USING @arg_date, @val1;` It still gave me error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your database structure is apparently wrong. there should be no such tables like `sample_table_?` at all. make it just `sample_table` **without**  binding table name parts

Comment: Noone need this escape character - so, it's okay to have it removed. it seems you are using concat instead of binding

Comment: Sorry for previous comment. It was result from another test version of same SP. @text_data was null because it is user variable not argument.  How can I directly use argument variable there

Comment: I fixed the code, But remember - you should bind only data literals, such as strings and numbers

Comment: Thank you very much. You help was invaluable